# Is there any difference between `x > 0` and `x > 0.0D` in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point

The following code is from the `Math.java` of java standard library:

```
public static double abs(double a) {
    return (a <= 0.0D) ? 0.0D - a : a;
}
```

I have questions that:

1. Is the code equal to `return (a <= 0) ? 0.0D - a : a;`
2. Furthermore, is the code euqal to `return (a <= 0) ?  - a : a;`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: D means that the constant is a double. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @jr593 double to int is a narrow down casting so obvious it's not done automatically. Only 0 will be upcast to `double`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a <= 0` when `a` is double converts `0` to `double` (due to binary numeric promotion), which means it's equivalent to `a <= 0.0D`.

`a <= 0.0D` might be more efficient, since it saves the conversion, but I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler converts `a <= 0` to `a <= 0.0D` in order to save that type conversion.

Relevant JLS quotes:

> [15.20.1. Numerical Comparison Operators <, <=, >, and >=](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1)
>
> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

> [5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)
>
> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

As for your second question, the code that uses unary negation operator is **not** equivalent to the code of the `abs` method, since:

> For floating-point values, negation is not the same as subtraction from zero, because if x is +0.0, then 0.0-x is +0.0, but -x is -0.0. Unary minus merely inverts the sign of a floating-point number.

([15.15.4. Unary Minus Operator -](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4))

BTW, the case of positive zero or negative zero is mentioned as a special case in the Javadoc of the `abs` method:

> Special cases:
>
> • If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, the result is positive zero.
>
> • If the argument is infinite, the result is positive infinity.
>
> • If the argument is NaN, the result is NaN.

The first two special cases are the cases in which `-a` differs from `0.0D - a`.

Comment: The compiler converts it.

Comment: specifically, both cases get compiled to use the same `dconst_0` opcode.  `javap -c` can be useful to see what the compiler is doing in cases like this